# Image resized correctly, but border goes around containing div?

Tags: html, image, css

Working on a gallery where pictures are resized within a square container, respecting aspect ratio. So far, so good. However, I cannot seem to get a border around the images themselves: the border shows around the square containers? [see codepen](https://codepen.io/eezacque/pen/YLwNQJ)

```css
.gallery {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.gallery .thumbnail {
  float: left;
  width: 18vw;
  height: 18vw;
}

.thumbnail img {
  border: 6px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<h1>Gallery...</h1>
<div class="gallery">
   <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="https://cdn.now.howstuffworks.com/media-content/e18fbc93-044b-4c18-ac52-15467d0db19f-640-360.jpg">
   </div>
   <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="https://cdn.europosters.eu/image/750/posters/looney-tunes-characters-i1344.jpg">
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

> just remove height from css

```css
<style media="screen" type="text/css">
    
             .gallery {
               overflow: hidden;
               position: relative;
             }
             .gallery .thumbnail {
                 float: left;
                 width: 18vw;
                 
             }
             .thumbnail img{
                 border: 6px solid black;
                 width: 100%;
                 object-fit: contain;
             }
    
          </style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
       <head>
          
       </head>
       <body>
          <h1>Gallery...</h1>
          <div class="gallery">
             <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="https://cdn.now.howstuffworks.com/media-content/e18fbc93-044b-4c18-ac52-15467d0db19f-640-360.jpg">
             </div>
             <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="https://cdn.europosters.eu/image/750/posters/looney-tunes-characters-i1344.jpg">
             </div>
          </div>
       </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: This crops a portrait image, which is not acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

You can make an approach using flexbox, this will fit your images an keep its aspect ratio...

```css
.gallery * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.gallery {
  overflow: hidden; /* or comment out this line */
  position: relative;
}

.gallery .thumbnail {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.thumbnail img {
  border: 6px solid black;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<h1>Gallery...</h1>
<div class="gallery">
   <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="https://cdn.now.howstuffworks.com/media-content/e18fbc93-044b-4c18-ac52-15467d0db19f-640-360.jpg" alt="">
   </div>
   <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="https://cdn.europosters.eu/image/750/posters/looney-tunes-characters-i1344.jpg" alt="">
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @VXp, I don't understand why you are bitter/frustrated.

Fact is you made a contribution that did not give the OP the answer he/she wanted, the modification made by Renzo Calla (no matter how small it is) did provide the answer he was looking for.

Therefore, he fixed, the OPs broken code, and your broken code to give the outcome the OP was seeking and thus should be credited for it, no matter how small the modification is.

Developers come across this... every... single day
Some of us miss a period or a coma in our code, credit is given to the developer that spots it.

End of

Comment: @VXp I ran your code and saw white space between the image and borders, which to my understanding the OP didnt want this

Renzo Calla's code when ran, ensures the border encapsulates the image, which was what the OP was asking for

So to answer your question... No im not kidding

Comment: Quoting the question:
"I cannot seem to get a border around the images themselves: the border shows around the square containers"

Comment: @DataCure Jesus, the border is already around the img's...that's what object-fit: contain; does you know. Your downvote makes no sense.

Comment: @VXp 

Please challenge your energy into answering another question, and get credited for your contribution, however my view regarding this question doesn't alter by the responses you have so far given

At this point I am going to end this conversation between us and wish you the best in answering questions in the future.

Comment: @VXp, Renzo Calla: thanks for sorting me out, you just made my day!